# Set-ADAccountExpiration in PowerShell sets AD account -1 day. Why?

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I have a csv with employee expiration dates formatted like 8/12/2016, but the `Set-ADAccountExpiration` cmdlet is setting the date 8/11/2016. I'm assuming this means 8/11/2016 11:59 PM? This appears to be a bug?

If the user's last day is on 8/12/2016, the last thing we want is for them to get to work that day and be expired. How do I fix this?

I'm using a `[string]` variable from the csv called `$Row.'Expiration Date'` but having difficulty doing the `.AddDays(1)` thing, since it's not `[DateTime]` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your row into a `[DateTime]`:

```psh
([DateTime]($Row.'Expiration Date')).AddDays(1)
```

Also, don't assume that the cmdlet is setting it to 11:59 PM; check for yourself:

```psh
Get-ADUser username -Properties AccountExpirationDate
```

[This page has a good writeup about this](http://mikefrobbins.com/2013/12/12/setting-an-active-directory-user-account-to-expire-at-a-specific-time-of-day-with-powershell/).

Comment: Right. Thanks for the syntax and have marked correct your answer. But, 12:00 AM on 8/12/2016 is what the Get-ADUser AccountExpirationDate returns, so even though that's the time in the attribute, it shows up as End of Day 8/11/2016. That's still not acceptable. End of Day 8/12/2016 should be 11:59 PM. How do I file a request to have the Set-ADAccountExpiration cmdlet changed?

Comment: @MarcGel [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell) is the place to go for that.