# New-ADUser in PowerShell, Account Expiration plus one day

Tags: csv, powershell, active-directory

This is the closest I have come to an answer:

[Set-ADAccountExpiration in PowerShell sets AD account -1 day. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31975380/set-adaccountexpiration-in-PowerShell-sets-ad-account-1-day-why)

However, it does not work in my case. I am creating new users with PowerShell in Active Directory. The account expiration is pulled from a CSV file like this:

```
$ExpireDate = $Line.'Contract Expiration'
    if ($ExpireDate -eq "") {$AccountExpiryDate = [DateTime]::Now.AddYears(1)}
    else {$AccountExpiryDate = $ExpireDate}
```

Then is added to the New-ADUser:

```
New-ADUser -Path $TestOU -SamAccountName $SamAccountName -AccountExpirationDate $AccountExpiryDate `
```

It pulls the date in just fine, but needs to be for the next day (I understand the 12:00am pullover). When I try this:

```
else {$AccountExpiryDate = ([DateTime]($Line.'Contract Expiration')).AddDays(1)}
```

It pulls the original date as if the AddDays(1) was not attached. Any ideas?

---

Solution found (thanks to Austin French)

```
$ExpireDate = $Line.'Contract Expiration'
    $nDate = [DateTime]::Parse($ExpireDate)
    if ($ExpireDate -eq "") {$AccountExpiryDate = [DateTime]::Now.AddYears(1)}
    else {$AccountExpiryDate = $nDate.AddDays(1)}
```

Comment: Tried parsing the date? Something like: `$nDate = [DateTime]::Parse($string);
$nDate.AddDays(1)`

Comment: Sweet, another note: A try/ catch would be a great idea in case of really malformed dates (so the whole script does not die!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suspicion is that the date in the column is not being cast properly to a DateTime object. Using the DateTime.Parse method would help verify the object and convert the string properly.

In your case try the following:

> $newDateTime = [DateTime]::Parse($Line.'Contract Expiration') 
>   $AccountExpiryDate = $newDate.AddDays(1)

Comment: This was it. Added working solution to original post.